# Remove Redis key deletion behavior on expiration

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Redis Key Space Notification to get my application notified when a specified key gets expired.

But when the key gets expired, Redis deletes the key, i need to remove this behavior because my application can use this expired information in another moment.

Is there a way to remove this behavior?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: That's the whole point behind setting a expiration on a key. You need to rethink your strategy and/or application if you actually need a value on a key where you set an expiration.

Comment: I understand, I think I'll have to resort to another strategy apparently, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

As @sazzad and @nitrin0 said, there's no way to change that.

As another option to get a similar result, I'd suggest you use a [sorted set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) to track these "psuedo-expirations", and when they "expire", a background process does whatever else you need the key for: move it, transform it, reset the expiration, etc.

Use the command [`zadd`](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) to both create a new sorted set and to add members to it. The key for the set can be anything, but I'd use the members as the keys from the data that expires so you can easily work with both the real data, and the member in the sorted set.

```sh
ZADD name-of-sorted-set NX timestamp-when-data-expires key-of-real-data
```

Let's break this down:

- `name-of-sorted-set` is what you'd use in the other `Z*` commands to work with this specific sorted set.
- `NX` means "Only add new elements. Don't update already existing elements.". The other option is `XX` which is "Only update elements that already exist. Don't add new elements." For this, the only options are `NX` or nothing.
- `timestamp-when-data-expires` is the `score` for this member, and we'll use it as the exact timestamp when the data would otherwise "expire", so you'll have to do some calculations in your application to provide the timestamp instead of just the seconds until it expires.
- `key-of-real-data` is the exact key used for the real data this represents. Using the exact key here will help easily combine the two when you're working with this sorted set to find which members have "expired", since the members are the keys you'd use to move, delete, transform, the data.

Next I'd have a background process run [`zrangebyscore`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to see if there are any members whose scores (timestamps) are within some range:

```sh
ZRANGEBYSCORE name-of-sorted-set min-timestamp max-timestamp WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 10
```

Let's break this down too:

- `name-of-sorted-set` is the key for the set we chose in `ZADD` above
- `min-timestamp` is the lower end of the range to find members that have "expired"
- `max-timestamp` is the higher end of the range
- `WITHSCORES` tells Redis to return the name of the members AND their scores
- `LIMIT` allows us to set an offset (the `0`) and a count of items to return (the `10`). This is just an example, but for very large data sets you'll likely have to make use of both the offset and count limits.

`ZRANGEBYSCORE` will return something like this if using `redis-cli`:

```sh
  1) "first-member"
  2) "1631648102"
  3) "second-member"
  4) "1631649154"
  5) "third-member"
  6) "1631650374"
  7) "fourth-member"
  8) "1631659171"
  9) "fifth-member"
 10) "1631659244"
```

Some Redis clients will change that, so you'll have to test it in your application. In `redis-cli` the member-score pair is returned over two lines.

Now that you have the members (keys of the actual data) that have "expired" you can do whatever it is you need to do with them, then probably either remove them from the set entirely, or remove them and replace them. Since in this example we created the sorted set with the `NX` example, we can't update existing records, only insert new ones.